# Angular JS custom delimiter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, configuration, delimiter

How do I use a custom delimiter for angular JS? I'd like to change from the `{{ var }}` syntax to `[[ var ]]`.

Can somebody show me a complete example on how to implement this with Angular?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use `$interpolateProvider` to change start / end symbols used for AngularJS expressions:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

and then, in your template:

```
Hello, [[name]]
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bvc62/3/

Check the documentation on the `$interpolate` service here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate

Comment: Tried still not working in my app, nothing happen angular still looking for {{ }} bracket.

Comment: Could you try to compare what is goin on in the setup of your web app to the fiddle I've sent? As you can see it works ok in the fiddle in the response. Watch out for code around module initialization. Are you specifing ng-app="myApp" like in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, how do we configure the custom brackets for modules like bootstrap.ui?`

Comment: Just starting with AngularJS and within Laravel 4 I loaded the framework and then added {{2+2}} to the view - nothing else at all and it evaluated to 4. Where do I put the code to change this to [[2+2]]? I've tried adding it between script tags on the same page and adding ng-app="myApp" to the containing div tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's an "official" fallback `startSymbol` and `endSymbol` that the community prefers to see?

Comment: FYI: `oModule.directive('myDirective', ['$interpolate', function ($interpolate) { /*...*/ }]);` is how I had to reference the `$interpolateProvider`, this was not imminently obvious (at least to me ;).

Comment: You can put the start and end symbols in one line now. Like this --> `$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');`

Comment: It's NOT working for me as well, i'm using laravel 5 and angular 1.3.0, html just renders [[variable]] as it is.

Comment: The Angular JS documentation link is not available anymore. The new link is [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider).