# How do I escape curly braces for display on page when using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want the user to see double curly braces, but Angular binds them automatically.  This is the opposite case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j) where they want to not see curly braces used for binding when the page is loading.

I want the user to see this:

```
My name is {{person.name}}.
```

But Angular replaces `{{person.name}}` with the value.  I thought this might work, but angular still replaces it with the value:

```
&#123;&#123;person.name}}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XBJjr6uR1rMAg3Ng7DiJ

Comment: If you are willing to go with another delimiter altogether (such as `[[ ]]`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923521/angular-js-custom-delimiter

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but the whole point is really for a sample page showing how the braces work and I want viewing the source to be able to look exactly like what's on the page showing the sample if that makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent double curly brace notation from displaying momentarily before angular.js compiles/interpolates document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866447/prevent-double-curly-brace-notation-from-displaying-momentarily-before-angular-j)

Comment: @MaximeLorant That is a completely different issue to do with preventing the momentary display of curly braces when the page is loading, this question is about getting them TO display even after the page has loaded and to prevent angular from binding them.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
<code ng-non-bindable>{{person.name}}</code>
```

Documentation @ [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

Comment: You could also use <div> or whatever tag, just add ng-non-bindable

Comment: what if the `{{value}}` is inside of an input tag value?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen, to output curly braces in an HTML *attribute* see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37473892/99777).

Comment: @TimoHuovinen You can use `ng-non-bindable` in container element, you can see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42511222/1407491

Comment: This doesn't work presently; using Angular 8. @joeytwiddle 's answer did however.

Comment: tested on ng13 ,does not work.probably deprecated

Comment: @JECarterII This question was for angularjs.  For angular, try [ngNonBindable](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#deactivating-angular-processing-with-ngnonbindable) like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwr4np?file=src%2Fmain.ts)  `<p ngNonBindable>Hello, {{name}}</p>`

Answer (score 31):

**Edit:**  adding \ slash between brackets inside the quotes works

```
{{  "{{ person.name }\}"   }}
```

this too .. by passes angular interpreting

```
{{ person.name }<!---->}
```

this too ..

```
{{ person.name }<x>} 

{{ person.name }<!>}
```

Comment: Gives me a `Lexer Error`

Comment: {{      '{{' asd '}}'   }}         what about his

Comment: This is a late answer to a question with an accepted answer.  If you choose to provide a new answer, you should take extra precautions to make sure the solution works, and should provide compelling reasons why this answer is preferred to the widely accepted answer.  Also, this doesn't directly answer the question anyway.

Comment: Like for this one `{{...}<!---->}`.

Answer (score 15):

In our case we wanted to present curly brackets in a placeholder, so they needed to appear inside an HTML *attribute*.  We used this:

```
 <input placeholder="{{ 'Hello {' + '{person.name}' + '}!' }}" ...>
```

As you can see, we are building up a string from three smaller strings, in order to keep the curly braces separated.

```
'Hello {' + '{person.name}' + '}!'
```

This avoids using `ng-non-bindable` so we can continue to use `ng-` attributes elsewhere on the element.

Comment: Works (as recently as angular 8).

Answer (score 10):

**Updated for Angular 9**

Use `ngNonBindable` to escape interpolation binding.

```
<div ngNonBindable>
  My name is {{person.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted single brackets across text and the above solutions didn't work for me. So did want the Angular recommended.

**Angular Version: 5**

Required Text: My name is {person.name}.

```html
<span>My name is {{'{'}}person.name{{'}'}}.</span>
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-non-bindable` in container, this is effective on all element inside here container.

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
  <span>{{person.name}}</span>
  <img src="#" alt="{{person.name}}">
  <input placeholder="{{person.name}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<span>{{</span>{{variable.name}}<span>}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Angular compiler:

```
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)
```

So in the original question - you would end up with:

```
My name is {{ '{' }}{{ '{' }}person.name{{ '}' }}{{ '}' }}
```