# Compiling text in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, frameworks, client-side

I have following template:

```
<h1 class="text-center" ng-bind-html="row.text"></h1>
```

If the content of my `row.text` is a string say:

```
  Hi your name is {{ name }}
```

It will display:

```
  Hi your name is {{ name }}
```

instead of the actual `{{ name }}` binding.

Do I need to eval or compile this row.text expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape curly braces for display on page when using AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs)

Comment: I realize after the edit that it may not be a duplicate.

Comment: You got no ng-model nor a binding `name`. Show more code

Comment: This is rather strange use of bindings and I guess there is a better way to do this. Could you explain why you have a template in a variable `row.text`? The pragmatic way to do it is to define a dedicated directive to just `Hi your name is {{ name }}` and in your case, you will need a generic directive which `$compile`s the template before appending it to the `$element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: After spending some time on the issue, I figured out that parse a string that can possibly contain AngularJS expressions, one way to do is below.

Say your $scope is: { "name": "my name" }

And your string expression is in variable v: var v = "Hello, {{ name }}"

```
var exp = $interpolate(v);
var result = exp($scope);
```

You will then get the following string in the result variable: Hello, my name

I will then inject the answer into the scope variable.

However, one issue with this is, once this is done, the result is a string, and therefore any changes to the "name" variable in the scope will no longer affect that particular evaluated expression.

Reference: [AngularJS $interpolate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interpolate)

2: If data binding is still important, what I did was instead of doing indirection like that, create a custom template string instead e.g. "Hello {{ name }}"

and compile it accordingly:

```
$compile($scope.row.text)($scope)
```

Reference: [AngularJS $compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

I tried both in a directive and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're going for:

http://jsfiddle.net/dMp55/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="ngAppDemo">
    <div ng-controller="ngAppDemoController">
      I can add: {{a}} + {{b}} =  {{ a+b }}
      <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="myHTML"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('ngAppDemo', []).controller('ngAppDemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
  $scope.myHTML = '{{a}}';
});
```

Output

```
I can add: 1 + 2 = 3
{{a}}
```

but I believe you will have to eval or compile the text...

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to achieve, I tried to compile but I believe compile can be used on templates only because it gave me some kind of invalid expression error. My expression is more like just an inner HTML expression. Eval I believe work on expressions such as "row.text" only not on the entire HTML string.

Comment: I believe $interpolate is the answer. Will check when I reach home (only hv an iPhone with me now) and update the thread.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle already with **$interpolate**. Thanks for setting it up. [http://jsfiddle.net/dMp55/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/dMp55/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using `$templateCache` as following:

**In Controller:**

```
myApp.controller('RowCtrl', function ($scope, $templateCache) {

    $scope.row = {
       id: 2,
       text: '{{ name }}'
    };

    var row_tmpl = 'row-tmpl-' + row['id'];
    $templateCache.put(row_tmpl, row.text);
    $scope.row_tmpl = row_tmpl;
});
```

**In Template:**

```
  <div ng-include src="row_tmpl" >

  </div >
```