# Ignore binding in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<span>
    {{Client.FirstName}}
    {{Client.LastName}}
</span>
```

Angular keeps trying to replace them with object values AS IT SHOULD. However, I want to ignore the binding in this case as I want to render it as it to the client.

Comment: Could you show your controller code?

Comment: I have no code for it right now, it pretty much is an empty controller. I just don't want the items inside the span to bind to anything in angular.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use an existing angular directive called "ngNonBindable" you can take a look here.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div> 
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```

Result for non-bindable is ---> {{1 + 2 }}

Answer (score 3):

use this `ng-non-bindable` for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

ex :

```
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<span ng-non-bindable>
   {{Client.FirstName}}
   {{Client.LastName}}
</span>
```