# Disable angular processing in a section of my html

Tags: angularjs

Can't find anything about this so here goes.

Can I instruct angular not to process `{{}}` interpolations in a certain section (div) of my html?

I have a place where `{{/}}` exists like this in my html:

```
<pre>
    <code class="some">{{asd}}Something{{/}}</code>
</pre>
```

Here angular is always trying to interpret `{{asd}}` and `{{/}}` and it's causing all kinds of errors. I really want angular not to look at the whole `pre`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just [escape curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868024/492258)

```
<pre>
    <code class="some" ng-non-bindable>{{asd}}Something{{/}}</code>
</pre>
```