# Escape expression curly braces

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a web tutorial for AngularJS using AngularJS. I'm using bootstrap `<pre></pre>` tags for some of the example code. I'm just wondering how do you go about escaping the curly brace `{{ }}` symbols from being processed as an AngularJS expression. I've tried html codes `&#123;` and `&#125;` but these are just processed as if they were the ASCII curly braces.

Comment: I'm using angular1

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs

Comment: @pietro909 Thank you! Turns out you can use <code></code> tags inside of <pre></pre> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<code></code>` tags inside of `<pre></pre>` tags.

With this you can use `<code ng-non-bindable>{{}}</code>`.

Orginial Solution:

[How do I escape curly braces for display on page when using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs)