# Angular is compiling a expression that shouldn't

Tags: angularjs

I'm just learning Angular and started with expressions.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>
            **Example {{ 5 + 5 }}**
        </p>
        <div>
            <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>
            **Example {{ firstName + ' ' + lastName }}**
        </p>
        <div ng-init="firstName='Daniel';lastName='Vieira Costa'">
            <p>My first expression: {{ firstName + ' ' + lastName }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that Angular is compiling a text that shouldn't compile. For each test, I have the following

** Example**

element. How to disable that to be compiled by Angular?

I want to show only the text, not the result.

Comment: Use `&#123;` and `&#125;` instead of `{}` http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: Hi @PaulAbbott, it works only the &#123; has an space from other &#123;, for example &#123; &#123; (work) &#123;&#123; (didn't work)

Comment: Oops, completely wrong.  You need `ng-non-bindable` on the `<p>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`ngNonBindable`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive by just adding the `ng-non-bindable` to the element that you don't want to be binded.

Consider this example:

```
    <p ng-non-bindable>
        **Example {{ 5 + 5 }}**
    </p>
    <div>
        <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
    </div>
```