# How to use jqmath script in angular application?

Tags: angular, jqmath

I'm developing a Quiz application where i want to use jqMath script to display the maths equations. Problem is that there is syntax conflict whenever i use curly braces other than that all equation format are working fine. I have tried interpolation provider but its still the same. How can i solve this. please help!

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) (" Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("
```

```js
import {parseMath} from 'jqmath';

export class A{
  
  @ViewChild('exp') exp:ElementRef;
  
  func{
    var  exp = this.exp.nativeElement;     
    parseMath(exp);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="exp" #exp >$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide more input on your question by adding descriptive code.

Comment: @MithunR. i've added it . please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used angular, but it appears that it is triggered by double curly braces. To avoid this, try putting a space between the two braces, i.e. `{ {` for `{{`, or `} }` for `}}`. jqMath will ignore the space inside mathematics.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it still the same. I know the problem is caused by angular delimiter "{ }" . If i can change this delimiter to some other symbol this problem might fix . The other way is to change the grouping symbol "{ }" used in jqMath ..

Comment: Ouch. It appears you could use ngNonBindable, or change the angular delimiter as you suggest. You can't change the "{}" characters in jqMath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs.