# Escape curly braces in condition Angular

Tags: angular

I have this case in which I want to check against a string that contains curly braces.
Data retrieved from object contains a string with curly braces.

```
             let defaultTitleFromComponentVar = 'Hello There';
             let dataList = ['Test1', 'Title2', '{{defaultTitle}}', 'Title3'];

             <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let title of dataList">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="title == '{{defaultTitle}}'">
                    {{ defaultTitleFromComponentVar }}
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="title != '{{defaultTitle}}'">
                    {{ title }}
                  </ng-container>  
                </li>
              </ul>
```

**Error get in console:**

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it 
isn't a known property of...
```

Comment: And does this **not** work? What's the output? Give a [mcve].

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868024/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-for-display-on-page-when-using-angularjs/37473892#37473892)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+escape+curly+braces

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have modified example

Comment: Still: *what's the output?*

Comment: no any output it gives error in console: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of...

Comment: That *is* the output - your examples should include the errors you're getting. It's unclear from the question why you think there's a problem at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right. I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe simply

```
*ngIf="title == '{{custTitle}\}'"
```

Comment: I want to check string that have curly braces.

Comment: try my modified answer then

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape every curly brace using `\` 
`*ngIf="title == '\{\{defaultTitle\}\}'`