# Escaping an Angular Template expression for display in an Angular HTML Component Template?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

If we are writing documentation within an Angular App is there a way to escape:

```
<p>{{ date | date :'short'}}</p>
```

So that it does not execute and instead renders as:

```
{{ date | date :'short'}}
```

Most sample documentation I've read through will put a `span` element around the individual pieces like this:

```
<span class="pun">{{</span>
```

Does angular have a syntax highlighting pipe that we can pass the expression through?

In AngularJS it's done like this:

```
 <div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552129/1009922).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ng-non-bindable`/`ngNonBindable` attribute to indicate Angular shouldn't compile the contents of that DOM element.

**Angular 8:**

In your case, the new code would look like `<p ngNonBindable>{{ date | date :'short'}}</p>`.

**AngularJS:**

In your case, the new code would look like `<p ng-non-bindable>{{ date | date :'short'}}</p>`.

More Info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable#examples

Comment: Turns out this is for AngularJS.  Do you know what the corresponding version for Angular 8 is?

Comment: It should be ngNonBindable then. Check out https://ngrefs.com/latest/templates/ngnonbindable.

@Ole