# How to escape interpolation markers {{ and }} to avoid execution by angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to escape interpolation markers `{{` and `}}` in the input string to avoid them being executed as interpolation by `angularjs 1.8.3`. These markers should be escaped by preceding each of their characters with a REVERSE SOLIDUS U+005C (backslash).

this is what I tried:

```
var inputString = "{{ code snippet here }}" ; 
inputString = inputString.replace("{{", "\\{\\{").replace("}}","\\}\\}");
```

WHen i set this string back to Html, it gets rendered in output Html as:

```
\{\{ code snippet here \}\}
```

I'm expected to show exactly the same as they were in inputString (without `\`)
How do I escape these markers without affecting them in output Html?

P.S. I can't use `ngNonBindable` which was mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868262) because I can't modify all the Html at this point. And also due to other project-specific reasons.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var nodeValue = "{{ 'sample snippet' }}";
nodeValue = nodeValue.replace('{{', '\\{\\{').replace('}}','\\}\\}');

document.getElementById('testtextarea').innerText = nodeValue;
```

```html
<div ng-app>

<textarea id="testtextarea" cols="50"></textarea>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.min.js"></script></div>
```

Comment: I might be missing something... Why u need to escape value? https://plnkr.co/edit/jbsUVnjspm8EupQ1 or do u set it before angular compiles element?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the characters with their relative [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity):

```
inputString = inputString.replace("{{", "&lcub;&lcub;").replace("}}","&rcub;&rcub;");
```

Comment: this is getting rendered as `&lcub;&lcub; code snippet here &rcub;&rcub;` in output `textarea`