# How you deal with translation (multilanguage) webservices in Django Rest Framework using angularjs?

Tags: django, rest, angularjs, translation, multilingual

I am a beginner with using: django, the django rest framework and the client-side MVC framework Angularjs.

I would like to ask any developers working or familiar with this stack in any of your projects, how you deal with translations (in many languages)?

What are best practices to do it as efficiently as possible and are there any new language extensions available?

Comment: I edited your post to make it read better, but I think it still might get closed because you're being very vague about what you need. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing specific to AngularJS about dealing with languages. If you want to handle the choice client-side, make sure to set the `Accept-Language` header. See the [django translation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language).

If you want to handle language choice server-side, you can use either [url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization), or set the `translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY` session key.

If you need to support translations for storage-backed data (i.e. models), [django-modeltranslation](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a pretty good package to use. It dynamically adds extra columns for fields you specify, one for each of `settings.LANGUAGES`, then lets you use the original column as a proxy to the value in the current active language.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use Django with AngularJS and use the same PO files for frontend and backend translations.

In the end I succeeded using [django-vinaigrette](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-vinaigrette) and [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). I created a model AngularTranslations with two [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396253/altering-mysql-table-column-to-be-case-sensitive) fields, orig and trans, with the same content. (A bit of waste, but OK). I registered the 'trans' field with Vinaigrette, and then I created an API GET-method that outputs the translations as JSON readable by angular-translate. I also allowed POST's to the same method to store missing translations. Vinaigrette then picks them up when running `manage.py makemessages`.

Can elaborate more but this is the gist of it.

Comment: On which part? In the meantime I got annoyed with Django PO files because they reset any time the English source translation is changed. I still use it for static content, but for dynamic content I am using django-parler. For django-parler-enabled models you can do the same as for the vinaigrette-models: pass the key-value pairs to Javascript somehow and load them there into angular-translate.

Answer (score 0):

I think good start point for someone, who would like in the future deal with translation in case of REST can be this article:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150504195746/http://codeispoetry.me:80/index.php/django-multilingual-restful-api-i18n-support-with-django-tastypie/

it forces usage of i18n, which is base of e.g django admin trans.

Comment: the link redirects to something else.

Comment: @freerunner update the answer with the link of archived page. https://web.archive.org/web/20150504195746/http://codeispoetry.me:80/index.php/django-multilingual-restful-api-i18n-support-with-django-tastypie/ Could you be so nice and undo your downvote?

Comment: Yes sure. Thanks for updating the link.