# What should I do if I do not want to use '{{ }}' in template of golang?

Tags: reactjs, go

I have to use `react` and `golang` together for some reason.
However, every time I need to use `{{ }}` in react, golang's turbulence overlaps with golang's template.
Is there any way that templates in golang will not work?
This should be partial and should not work as a whole because I have to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape “{{” and “}}” delimiters in Go templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641887/how-do-i-escape-and-delimiters-in-go-templates)

Comment: Externalize your React stuff from your templates  and use something like [go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice) to embed your resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the delimiters on the Go side to something else before parsing (for example you could use [[ ]] ).

See the docs:

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims

Comment: Could you give me an example or something?

Comment: Instead of `template.Execute(...)` you do `template.Delims("[[", "]]").Execute(...)`