# How to escape "{{" and "}}" in argo workflow

Tags: go-templates, kubeflow, argo-workflows, argoproj

I want to run one argo workflow in which a value is surrounded with double braces. Argo tries to resolve it but I don't want argo to resolve it.

Following is a fraction of katib studyjob workflow manifest.

```
workerSpec: 
  goTemplate: 
    rawTemplate: |-
        apiVersion: "kubeflow.org/v1beta1"
        kind: TFJob
        metadata:
          name: {{.WorkerID}}
          namespace: kubeflow
```

Here argo tries to resolve {{.WorkerID}}. But I don't want argo to resolve it.

How can I do this? How can I escape "{{" and "}}"?

Comment: Did you find an answer? In helm, this should work: `{{ "{{.WorkerID}}" }}`, not sure about argo though but if it uses the same go template it might.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape “{{” and “}}” delimiters in Go templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641887/how-do-i-escape-and-delimiters-in-go-templates)

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a template literal, assuming you're using Helm templates

```
name: {{ `{{.WorkerID}}` }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `{% raw %}` tag:

`{% raw %} {{.WorkerID}} {% endraw %}`

[Jinja2 Reference](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#escaping)

Comment: Kubernetes YAML doesn't use Jinja