# How can I use Argo Workflows templates in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argoproj

Is it possible to use Helm to deploy Argo workflows? I get an error like below when I do a `helm install`

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: parse error at
> (workflows/templates/my_dag.yaml:47): function "workflow" not defined

The yaml itself has both Argo and Helm interpolations with `{{..}}`. I understand why it fails. Is there a way around this?

I've had a look at [this](https://tempered.works/posts/2020-05-21-helm-argo/) but it does not look like something I want to do as it sort of changes the syntax.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible. I've been on a team that regularly deployed Helm-templated WorkflowTemplates.

There are two ways to work around the Helm/Argo template tag collision. (As you know, the issue is that Helm's Go templating language and Argo's templating language both use `{{}}` to denote templated areas.)

## Option 1:

The first way is to **carefully nest the tags**. For example, if I want to use `{{steps.hello-world.result}}` as an Argo-template, I can write it as `` {{`{{steps.hello-world.result}}`}} ``. The outer `{{` tells Helm to start interpreting templated code. The backtick tells Helm to interpret the backtick-delimited contents literally. And finally, the inner `{{` is installed in the cluster as a plain-text part of the Workflow and eventually interpreted by Argo as a template.

Here's a modified version of the [arguments-parameters example](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/arguments-parameters.yaml) modified to be deployed with Helm.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: arguments-parameters-
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: message
      value: hello world
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: message
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["{{`{{inputs.parameters.message}}`}}"]
```

## Option 2:

The second work-around is described in the blog post you linked. That approach *does* change the syntax. The first approach uses a funny-looking syntax, but it is still technically just Helm's and Argo's default syntax.

If the `` {{`{{yikes}}`}} `` work-around doesn't solve your error message, please post the whole workflow (or a redacted/simplified version), and I'd be happy to take a look.

**Related:**

The above is for Argo-in-Helm (Jinja2-in-Go) templating. If you need somethingelse-in-Argo (somethingelse-in-Jinja2) templating, where somethingelse also uses `{{`, check out this answer: [How to escape "{{" and "}}" in argo workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56341558/684776)

Comment: Do you have an example.? I escaped the {{ and shows as chart is installed, but I could see the workflow template or workflows when listed.

Comment: @saranyaelumalai added an example

Comment: @saranyaelumalai sounds like that could be any number of issues... you should probably open a new question. I'll see it, I lurk on the `argo-workflow` tag. :-)

Comment: @crenshaw-dev I've been working with this syntax for a while now and still didn't figure out how the correct syntax for an evaluation with a parameter in the string looks like, example:
value:'{{`{{= inputs.parameters.repo == "devops" ? inputs.parameters.path : "kubernetes/{{inputs.parameters.repo}}" }}`}}'

Can you help me here?

Comment: @JDK92 I don't really like nesting Argo Workflows interpolation tags. Technically I think it's supposed to work, but I don't trust it. I'd do something like this: `{{= inputs.parameters.repo == "devops" ? inputs.parameters.path : ("kubernetes/" + inputs.parameters.repo)}}`. Of course wrap that expression in the Helm string literal syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put all your Argo Workflow templates in a separate directory besides `/templates` e.g. `raw-files` and include them in your helm deployment with the following template:

```
{{ range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  "raw-files/*" }}
---
{{ $.Files.Get $path }}
{{ end }}
```

With this approach, you can still lint the workflow templates with `argo lint` and use the [JSON schema integration](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/ide-setup/) of your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It Option1 fail an other workaround can be

```
{{ "{{inputs.parameters.message}}"|quote}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue and tried crenshaw-dev's solution, and it didn't work. Helm would throw the following message multiple times:

```
unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"tasks.data-formatting.outputs.parameters.employee-username-enc":interface {}(nil)}
```

The way I fixed it was by wrapping the escaped Argo statements with double quotes, like so:

```
# ...
arguments:
  parameters:
    - name: first-name
      value: "{{ `{{tasks.data-formatting.outputs.parameters.employee-username-enc}}` }}"
```

After

Hope it helps!