# AngularJS write custom delimiters compliant directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using an angular library which is written using the `{{` `}}` delimiters. For some reason I had to change the delimiters for my project (let's say I'm using `[[` `]]`)

The problem is that the library's directives are written using the regular delimiters `{{` `}}` and are therefore NOT [interpolated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) the right way anymore.

Is there a way to write a directive able to interpolate the arguments whatever the current delimiter ?

Comment: best guess is you won't be able to switch since you would have had to made your changes in angular config.

Comment: Have you considered using the "ng-bind" directive in place of {{ }} in your html code? <span ng-bind="foo"> can be used almost everywhere {{foo}} can be used.

Comment: @PrahladYeri the [directive I'm using](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/item.js) is interpolating attribute using the `{{` `}}`notation. If ng-bind works for the content itself, is there something for the attributes ? By writing this I do realise they might simply change their template using dynamically fetched delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If ng-bind works for the content itself, is there something for the attributes ?

Use the `ng-bind:` class attribute value template syntax. For example:

```
<div class="ng-bind: expression;"> ... </div>
```

Directive declaration styles have four variations:

```
E - Element name (default): <my-directive></my-directive>
A - Attribute (default): <div my-directive="exp"></div>
C - Class: <div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>
M - Comment: <!-- directive: my-directive exp -->
```

**References**

- [AngularJS API: Compile Service, Directive Definition Object - restrict](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict-)
- [Attribute Value Templates](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-attribute-value-templates)

Comment: Not precisely what I was looking for, but okay cause it can also works in some cases. I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923521/angular-js-custom-delimiter) which helps in getting the current "startSymbol" and "endSymbol" and can then be used for forging the right "handlebars".