# Configuration {{}} symbol in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know is it possible to change {{}} symbol in AngularJS,as other technology which I am using use same expression syntax to represent data on View.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can almost completely forego the usage of `{{}}` in angular with `ng-bind`.

Comment: It already has a response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can :

> You can use $interpolateProvider to change start / end symbols used
>   for AngularJS expressions:
>
> `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider)
>   {
>       $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{{');
>       $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}}'); 
>   });`

Found here : [Angular JS custom delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923521/angular-js-custom-delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

See $interpolateProvider : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

$interpolateProvider.startSymbol, $interpolateProvider.endSymbol